Strong text a bit too strong
In the new site design I think that the bold style is a bit too strong.
This can be fixed by using Semi-Bold font face, i.e. replacing:
b,strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

with
b,strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}

This should reduce the volume of shouting on the site.

Note sure if this is allowed by the SE rules of course - but it seems an improvement....

OK, not acceptable by the design team it seems. Again, you can change this in your browser using the Stylish add-on / extension. Crypto users: please remove **bold** and ***bold*** from text where it doesn't belong. Hell bells, the escape sequence doesn't work for bold and italic but you understand what I mean.
